# Publishing a RAW file after retouching RAW in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, raw-format, post-press

Ive been requested by a magazine to supply photos in a RAW format.

We get the files as RAWs from our photographer, but then touch them up / colour balance etc.

Is there a way to then republish them as RAW from Photoshop ? As i dont really want to send un post processed photos off to be published / touched up by a 3rd party out of our control.

Answer (score 2):

Once you open the file in photoshop the raw data is processed and can't be undone.
While editing in Adobe CameraRAW you´ll have all the sensor data to work with and all adjusts are registered into a separated **xml file** with same name. You can send that file enclosed to the original raw file or save it as **.dng** file (within CameraRaw interface) with that xml info embedded.
When your customer tries to open, it will do with your preview adjusts/corrections.

Anyway, they'll be able to change your adjusts so I think you have to advert them about retouching on their own responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, RAW is not a image format but a designation for a family of formats that contain (most of the time) the sensor data of your image. The raw data is thus not an image yet.

The process of turning the data into a viewable image is not very likely to be easily reversible. The data does not consist of pixels, ergo no 1:1 mapping. This is not to say it cannot be done just not easy to do.

Presumably this is exactly the point. The magazine wants to see your photography skill instead of your retouching skill.

Comment: In lue of providing a RAW would the next best thing be a TIFF of the processed image ? Re. wanting to see photography skill, actually thats the odd thing its a product review so nothing to do with photography skill, i guess they just want the most high res image.

Comment: In that case, saving it as a non-compressed 16/32 bit TIF is the maximum quality from the raw file.

Comment: It's not about "the most high res image", @sam, it's about RAW - they want to ensure they have an unretouched image. You can submit a TIFF or a low-compression JPEG *alongside* the RAW, but they want to see the RAW image. (A DNG with your basic ACR adjustments in place might be preferable from your point of view, since if you give them a RAW + XMP, there's no guarantee that they'll see your adjustments at all.)

Comment: @sam actually it sort of makes sense to ask for raw images for this purpose. Tough the photography setting can be manipulated quite much. ASK them.